# Why doesn't Typescript throw an error if we call a function without parenthesis?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have been working on Typescript for some time and have noticed this strange behaviour. Typescript doesn't throw an error if you call a function without parenthesis. It rather prints the entire function on the console. Why is that? I don't see such behaviour in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions are first-class members in JavaScript (and TypeScript is an extension of JavaScript). They can be assigned to variables and passed around just like any other expression like numbers and strings and arrays - *as long as it's typed properly* (in TypeScript).

```js
const fn = () => {
  return 10;
};

const bar = fn;
const result = bar();
console.log(bar);
console.log(result);
```

Since `console.log` permits literally any argument type, it's not forbidden to log functions in TypeScript.

But if you tried to reference the function *without* calling it, when you actually needed to call it to extract the return value, you would very quickly run into errors once you try to use the result. For example:

```
const subArr = arr.slice();
```

creates a shallow portion of the array. If you accidentally did

```
const subArr = arr.slice;
```

and then tried to use `subArr` anywhere that its type was expected to be an array, TypeScript would throw an error, since it determined that `subArr` is of type `function`, not of type `Array`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not related to typescript, instead javascript does that. It will print whatever you give to console log. So if you give function name without paranthesis, it will print function definition.